# Запуск MySQL в фоновом режиме

Tags: скрипт, mysql

Здравствуйте, мне надо, что бы пользователь, не понимающий ничего в компьютерах запустил один файл и у него на компьютере установилась MySQL создался пользователь и открылся доступ а всё остальное делал я удалённо, т.е. какой скрипт надо для этого написать

Comment: Самое простое Skype share screen.

Answer (score 1):

Можно наверное попробовать сделать через [Inno-Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), либо через любой другой инсталлер.